# How do I clear input buffer after a failed scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf, input-buffer

I have a problem with `scanf()` and input buffer in my program.

First I ask the user for input :

```
char someVariable;
printf("Enter text: ");
scanf(" %c",&someVariable);
```

Then I have a loop that goes over the input one char at a time using `scanf()` until it reaches a newline.

The problem is that after the loop is done, somehow, there is still something in the buffer so this function (which is being called in a loop) gets called again and ruins the logic in my program.

How can I force clear the input buffer?

I can only use `scanf()` (assignment requirements)

```
void checkType(){
    char userInput;
    char tempCheckInput;
    printf("Enter Text: ");
    scanf(" %c",&userInput);
    while (userInput != '\n'){

        tempCheckInput = userInput;
        scanf("%c",&userInput);
```

Ignore the end of the loop; this is the part where I get the input.

Comment: Show us the code, see [mcve].

Comment: @user3386109 it's a long..ish program so i don't want to copy over 100 lines, i'll edit the post one sec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely clear stdin and the \n before scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772103/how-to-completely-clear-stdin-and-the-n-before-scanf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can i force clear the input buffer?

In C, a *stream*, like `stdin`, cannot be cleared (in a standard way) as in "delete all input up to this point in *time*".

Instead input can consume and toss (akin to "cleared") input up to a data condition.

The usually way is

```
int consume_rest_of_line(void) {
  int ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    ;
  }
}
```

If limited to `scanf()`

```
int consume_rest_of_line(void) {
  char ch;
  while (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1 && ch != '\n') {
    ;
  }
}
```